# Laravel : execute function in controller

Tags: laravel, function, controller

I am beginner in Laravel , trying to get unused random id by create this controller :

```
class Trainer_controller extends Controller
{
public function add(Request $request)
    {
     $id= get_id();
     dd($id);
    }
public function get_id()
    {
        $id = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999); 
        if(check__id($id)){
            get_id();
        }
        return $id;
    }

    public function check_id($id)
    {
        $trainer=Trainer::where('id',$id)->get();
        if (count($trainer)==0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I get error said : `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\course\get_id()`
How can I solve it ?

Comment: use $this->get_id(); You should use always $this-> when you call any function in same controller.

Comment: opppppppppssssss How I missed that , thank you too much

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should consider declaring both get_id() and check_id() as Helper functions as you further develop your application instead of bloating your Controller with such logic.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers

Comment: did you mean to make a seperate class contain get_id and check_id methods then call them in controller?

Comment: Yes. If you want these methods to be available to multiple controllers. Decisions like these are usually at the mercy of your function's scale.